# How to search for two elements that meet certain conditions, emit an element and continue searching in RxJava?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a Flowable (cold) that I need the following operator applied on:

1. Go through the elements of the stream in order until one meets condition A. Cache the element that meets this condition.
2. Continue with the next element, but now check for condition B. If an element that meets this condition is found
3. Apply a function that accepts both elements previously collected and emit a new element on a second stream.
4. Continue until there are no elements left that first meet condition A and an element after that which meets condition B. Drop any cached elements.

*Note that after emitting, the next element that is checked for A should be the same that just met condition B, since an element may meet both conditions.*

I can't think of a way to do this with RxJava. My first instincts were takeUntil() and/or skipUntil(), but both are only applied once. And I don't have enough experience with reactive programming yet to write a custom operator.

Any thoughts and directions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter out A and B, collect them into a list, then check the list for subsequent A & B, apply a function add the result to a list and return that list into a `flatMapIterable`:

```java
source
.filter(v -> isA(v) || isB(v))
.toList()
.flatMapIterable(list -> {
     List<C> result = new ArrayList<C>();

     for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
         T a = list.get(i);
         T b = list.get(i + 1);
         if (isA(a) && isB(b)) {
             result.add(functionAB(a, b));
             i++;
         }
     }

     return result;
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems like the correct approach here ^^ But do we really need a List here? I think a `buffer(2, 1)` followed by another `filter()` and then `map()` would do the same without having to use those pesky standard Java objects ;D

Comment: Sure, the important thing is that you got the idea.